# Points appearing from bottom in Camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-augmented-reality

Currently I am using the Git-hub library for making a demo-App for AR-Location based project. I am using [AR-Location Based Android](https://github.com/dat-ng/ar-location-based-android). The library is working fine in portrait mode but in landscape mode the Ar-points are coming from bottom of screen(like bubbles comes out from bottom) and hide to top of screen, while rotating camera.I raised issues in Git also, but the owner is not responding. I tried to fix it, but unable to do it. Can anyone guide me to solve the problem. Or where to change.

I think this classes are responsible for plotting in **portrait** and **Landscape** mode. If not please tell me where to change.

```
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public class ARCamera extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "ARCamera";

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Camera.Size previewSize;
    List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera camera;
    Camera.Parameters parameters;
    Activity activity;

    float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];

    int cameraWidth;
    int cameraHeight;
    private final static float Z_NEAR = 0.5f;                   //Increase or decrease distance, between poines
    private final static float Z_FAR = 2000;

    public ARCamera(Context context, SurfaceView surfaceView) {
        super(context);

        this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        surfaceHolder = this.surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
        if (this.camera != null) {
            supportedPreviewSizes = this.camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
            Camera.Parameters params = this.camera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                this.camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (supportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = right - left;
            final int height = bottom - top;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (previewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = previewSize.width;
                previewHeight = previewSize.height;
            }

            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (camera != null) {

                parameters = camera.getParameters();

                int orientation = getCameraOrientation();

                camera.setDisplayOrientation(orientation);
                camera.getParameters().setRotation(orientation);

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    private int getCameraOrientation() {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT, info);

        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Rotation = " + rotation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Degrees = " + degrees, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Degrees = " + degrees, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int orientation;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            orientation = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            orientation = (360 - orientation) % 360;
        } else {
            orientation = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return orientation;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }


    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) width / height;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = height;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
                continue;
            }

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            optimalSize = sizes.get(0);
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (camera != null) {
            this.cameraWidth = width;
            this.cameraHeight = height;

            Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            try {
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            generateProjectionMatrix();
        }
    }

    private void generateProjectionMatrix() {
        float ratio = (float) this.cameraWidth / this.cameraHeight;

        final int OFFSET = 0;
        final float LEFT = -ratio;
        final float RIGHT = ratio;
        final float BOTTOM = -1;                //increases the speed of points going
        final float TOP = 1;                    //increases the speed of points coming


        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, OFFSET, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM, TOP, Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);
    }

    public float[] getProjectionMatrix() {
        return projectionMatrix;
    }
}
```

Activity Class

```
public class ARActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {

    final static String TAG = "ARActivity";
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private FrameLayout cameraContainerLayout;
    private AROverlayView arOverlayView;
    private Camera camera;
    private ARCamera arCamera;
    private TextView tvCurrentLocation;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private final static int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 11;
    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 0;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;//1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public Location location;
    boolean isGPSEnabled;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled;
    boolean locationServiceAvailable;

    private DisplayMetrics metrics;
    private RelativeLayout infoLayout;
    private ImageView appLogo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ar);
        Utility.getFullScreenView(this);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        cameraContainerLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_container_layout);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        tvCurrentLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location);
        infoLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_layout);
        appLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoApp);

        arOverlayView = new AROverlayView(this);

        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        infoLayout.getLayoutParams().width = metrics.widthPixels/4;
        appLogo.getLayoutParams().width = metrics.widthPixels/5;
        appLogo.getLayoutParams().height = metrics.heightPixels/4;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestLocationPermission();
        requestCameraPermission();
        registerSensors();
        initAROverlayView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        releaseCamera();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void requestCameraPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        } else {
            initARCameraView();
        }
    }

    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        } else {
            initLocationService();
        }
    }

    public void initAROverlayView() {
        if (arOverlayView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) arOverlayView.getParent()).removeView(arOverlayView);
        }
        cameraContainerLayout.addView(arOverlayView);
    }

    public void initARCameraView() {
        reloadSurfaceView();

        if (arCamera == null) {
            arCamera = new ARCamera(this, surfaceView);
        }
        if (arCamera.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) arCamera.getParent()).removeView(arCamera);
        }
        cameraContainerLayout.addView(arCamera);
        arCamera.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        initCamera();
    }

    private void initCamera() {
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(numCams > 0){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open();
                camera.startPreview();
                arCamera.setCamera(camera);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void reloadSurfaceView() {
        if (surfaceView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) surfaceView.getParent()).removeView(surfaceView);
        }

        cameraContainerLayout.addView(surfaceView);
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            arCamera.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private void registerSensors() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            float[] rotationMatrixFromVector = new float[16];
            float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
            float[] rotatedProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrixFromVector, sensorEvent.values);

            if (arCamera != null) {
                projectionMatrix = arCamera.getProjectionMatrix();
            }

            Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, rotationMatrixFromVector, 0);
            this.arOverlayView.updateRotatedProjectionMatrix(rotatedProjectionMatrix);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        //do nothing
    }

    private void initLocationService() {

        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return  ;
        }

        try   {
            this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Get GPS and network status
            this.isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            this.isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isNetworkEnabled && !isGPSEnabled)    {
                // cannot get location
                this.locationServiceAvailable = false;
            }

            this.locationServiceAvailable = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null)   {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    updateLatestLocation();
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled)  {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null)  {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    updateLatestLocation();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)  {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());

        }
    }

    private void updateLatestLocation() {
        if (arOverlayView !=null && location != null) {

            arOverlayView.updateCurrentLocation(location);
            tvCurrentLocation.setText(String.format("lat: %s \nlon: %s \naltitude: %s \n",
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateLatestLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    public void showHideInfo(View view) {
        infoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        infoLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in));
    }

    public void closeInfo(View view) {
        infoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        infoLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
    }
}
```

LocationHelper Class

```
public class LocationHelper {
    private final static double WGS84_A = 6378137.0;                  // WGS 84 semi-major axis constant in meters
    private final static double WGS84_E2 = 0.00669437999014;          // square of WGS 84 eccentricity

    public static float[] WSG84toECEF(Location location) {
        double radLat = Math.toRadians(location.getLatitude());
        double radLon = Math.toRadians(location.getLongitude());

        float clat = (float) Math.cos(radLat);
        float slat = (float) Math.sin(radLat);
        float clon = (float) Math.cos(radLon);
        float slon = (float) Math.sin(radLon);

        float N = (float) (WGS84_A / Math.sqrt(1.0 - WGS84_E2 * slat * slat));

        float x = (float) ((N + location.getAltitude()) * clat * clon);
        float y = (float) ((N + location.getAltitude()) * clat * slon);
        float z = (float) ((N * (1.0 - WGS84_E2) + location.getAltitude()) * slat);

        return new float[] {x , y, z};
    }

    public static float[] ECEFtoENU(Location currentLocation, float[] ecefCurrentLocation, float[] ecefPOI) {
        double radLat = Math.toRadians(currentLocation.getLatitude());
        double radLon = Math.toRadians(currentLocation.getLongitude());

        float clat = (float)Math.cos(radLat);
        float slat = (float)Math.sin(radLat);
        float clon = (float)Math.cos(radLon);
        float slon = (float)Math.sin(radLon);

        float dx = ecefCurrentLocation[0] - ecefPOI[0];
        float dy = ecefCurrentLocation[1] - ecefPOI[1];
        float dz = ecefCurrentLocation[2] - ecefPOI[2];

        float east = -slon*dx + clon*dy;

        float north = -slat*clon*dx - slat*slon*dy + clat*dz;

        float up = clat*clon*dx + clat*slon*dy + slat*dz;

        return new float[] {east , north, up, 1};
    }
}
```

I think first two classes are responsible for it. But I am not able to do so. Please guide me.